# How can I set up a component in a-frame that aggregates data from other components attached to the same entity?

Tags: aframe

**Scenario**

I am trying to create a 2 component 'system' whereby there is one master, `aggregator` component and multiple sub `source` components that feed data to the aggregator. Once all the data is received, the aggregator component will then run some functions on the parent entity. I am using a-frame `0.8.2`.

---

**Minimal example**

To demonstrate the logic in its simplest form, below is an example where 3 sub components are attached to an entity and each pass a string to the parent component by pushing them into an array that is part of the aggregator component's schema.

Here is the master component `aggregator`

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('aggregator', {

        schema: {
            testarray: {type: 'array', default: []},
        },

        update: function(){
            //to demonstrate problem
            console.log(this.data.testarray)
        },

})
```

And the sub component `source`

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('source', {

        dependencies: ['aggregator'],

        multiple: true,

        schema: {
            teststring: {type: 'string', default: ''},
        },

        init: function(){          
            var string = this.data.teststring
            var aggArray = this.el.getAttribute('aggregator').testarray
            aggArray.push(string)
            this.el.setAttribute('aggregator', 'testarray', aggArray)          
        },

})
```

And here is the HTML to test it

```
<a-scene>
      <a-entity
        id="aggregatortest"
        source__one="teststring:testone"
        source__two="teststring:testtwo"
        source__three="teststring:testthree">
      </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

[Here is a glitch](https://pushy-minibus.glitch.me/) (not much to see obviously but if you open the console you will see an 'empty' array (not actually empty but appears so).

---

**The problem**

As you will see if you run or look at the above example, the aggregator component's `testarray` is 'empty' on update. I know that the data is actually being successfully passed as if I look at the component in the console, I can see the array has been updated with the values as it is in the components `data`, it is not updated however. This is an issue because if I try to run some functions (depending on the passed data) in the aggregator's update, it does not work.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to wait for something to load? or some internal event? I would expect that every time the `source` component is initialised (in this case 3 times), it would force an update in the `aggregator` component which apparently is it is, somehow, but not in a way that I can work with since I cannot access the updated schema's properties in the update function.

Any advice would be much appreciated, if any more info or real context would be helpful, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tldr**: instead of grabbing the reference to `testarray` clone it:

```
var aggArray = this.el.getAttribute('aggregator').testarray.slice(0)
```

like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6orfzk4h/). Cloning @slice(0) was recommended by David Walsh [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array).

---

---

With this simple statement

```
var aggArray = this.el.getAttribute('aggregator').testarray
```

You grab a reference to the `testarray`.

---

In consequence, any changes to the `aggArray` are applied to the `aggregator.testarray`. Check it out in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3brhnts/). I removed the `setAttribute` bit, and the array still has new elements.

Now, keep in mind, if both arrays are the same, the update won't even fire - why would it, both the old data, and new are exactly the same.

In conclusion, you must provide a copy / clone of the array -> so the update function can work properly.

Comment: Thought it was a bug for a while, glad i'm working with those damn c++ pointers at work :D

Comment: Thank you Piotr, that works perfectly. Thanks also for the explanation. I'd appreciate if you could elaborate a bit for my understanding. Firstly, I understand when you say the update wouldn't fire if the values were the same each time, but I didn't think they were? Each time the source is initiated, its pushing a new item into the array so it would be different wouldn't it? Secondly, in your 2nd example, I can see you were managing to work with the new array in the tick function, is there any other function you could use that would have access to the data since init nor update do not?

Comment: @Nick, I'll try to explan 1) as soon as i have some time, as for 2) - you can access the data from any function in the component - since its a member of the component : https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/rntvjdu9/2/

Comment: Thanks Piotr, I think I understand - i make a reference to the original array which lets say at that point has 1 item in it, then I push another to it, now has 2, so by the time I setAttribute() with the new array of 2, it already has 2 in it. If that is correct, then I guess my confusion stems from my expectation that the update function would fire if any element of the component changes - in any way - but it would seem that those changes need to be made in particular ways like via setAttribute() to get updates to fire? if so then,I wonder if you can manually trigger the update function?